# Cout not returning any output

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ and found a problem that I dont understand. I have this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Person
{
    string * name;
public:
    Person(const string & n) : name {new string {n}} {}
    ~Person() {delete name;}
    string getName() const {return *name;}
};


int main()
{
    vector<Person> people;

    people.push_back(Person("Tom"));

    cout << "Name is: " << people.back().getName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I have no output. Dont know why? However, when I do simillar, but without vector everything is ok:

```
int main()
{
    Person tom {"Tom"};

    cout << "Name is: " << tom.getName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _`string * name;`_ Why for heaven's sake you're using a pointer, instead of a plain member varialble: `string name;`? Copies as made with `people.push_back(Person("Tom"));` will just miserably fail, and lead to results as you experience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As other said, better to do without pointers. However, if you wondering what is happening, the reason for what you get is that in this line `people.push_back(Person("Tom"));` Person object is created, and its copy passed to vector. However, once the object is copied, destructor is executed which deletes the string.

With your usage of pointers, both the original Person object and its copy point to the same string in memory. String gets deleted by destructor, and `name` pointer in the copy does not point to anything. Thus you get undefined behaviour.

To rectify this issue, either dont use pointers, or you need to define your own copy constructor. For example:

```
class Person
{
    string * name;
public:
    Person(const string & n) : name {new string {n}} {}

    // copy constructor which makes new string in memory
    //based on the original string.
    Person(const Person & other) {
        name = new string(other.getName());
    }

    ~Person() { delete name; }
    string getName() const {return *name;}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong type. Your `string` is already a string type. Write the code like this.

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person (const string& n) : name(n) { }
    ~Person() {}

    string getName() const { return name; }
private:
    string name;
};
```

If you insist to use pointer in your member variable, you shall overwrite the copy constructor and overload assign operator.

Give you an example:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person (const char* n)   : name(new char[strlen(n)+1])      { strcpy(name, n);      }
    Person (const Person& p) : name(new char[strlen(p.name)+1]) { strcpy(name, p.name); }
    ~Person() { delete [] name; }

    Person& operator=(const Person& p)
    {
        if ( &p == this ) return *this;
        delete [] name;
        name = new char[strlen(p.name)+1];
        strcpy(name, p.name);
        return *this;
    }

    string getName() const { return name; }

private:
    char* name;
};
```

Comment: When keeping the pointer, there is no reason to change the code to use a `char*`, especially since you are not deleting it correctly (it is allocated with `new[]`, so it has to be freed with `delete[]`).  Using a `string*` pointer was just fine, the only missing piece was the copy constructor to create a new `string` object.  Changing to `char*` actually creates more work that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code is buggy has already been explained, but if you have C++11, you can use `emplace_back`:

```
people.emplace_back("Tom");
```

Still, using pointers instead of a plain member variable is just unnecessarily complicating your program. The less memory management you have to do, the better. Read about the [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/). Better yet, if your `getName()` function doesn't do anything special, remove it and just make `name` public.

Comment: *"if you have C++11, you can use emplace_back:"* - I think it needs to be mentioned that that's not enough to be safe in general (e.g. if further operations on the `vector` triggered a resize and consequent element copying).  The `People` class is buggy as written, even if the current program modified - to use `emplace_back` - would not triggering that bug....

Comment: Making `name` public would mean that `name` can be modified at will. The original code did not provide a `setName()` method, so presumably the OP does not want outside code being able to modify `name` directly.